# Connect project via local maven (in Eclipse)

Tags: eclipse, maven, repository

In Eclipse, I can create dependency project and refer it from `Projects` tab from `Java Build Path` dialog.

May I substitute this with something "mavenish"?

For example, may be I can post maven project to local repository and then refer it by maven coordinates as usually in pom.xml?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you could install it to your local maven repository (`mvn install`). But it also works if you just have the project in your workspace you don't even have to refer it from `Java Build Path` as you've mentioned. Just add it as a dependency in your pom and the maven plugin in eclipse will use the dependency from your workspace.